# jQuery Slideshow number of thumbnails issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow with thumbnails on a bottom. The problem is there is 9 pictures loaded on to the slider but there is only 3 thumbnails, while slideshow goes through all 9 pictures. Attached is a js code. Thank you

```
    function comSlider603737() { 
    var self = this; 
    var g_HostRoot = "";
    var g_TransitionTimeoutRef = null;
    var g_CycleTimeout = 5;
    var g_currFrame = 0;
    var g_fontLoadJsRetries = 0;
    var g_currDate = new Date(); var g_currTime = g_currDate.getTime();            var     g_microID = g_currTime + '-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1); 
var g_InTransition = 0;var g_Navigation = 0;this.getCurrMicroID = function() { return g_microID; }; 
this.comSLoadImgInFrame = function(frameid, src) 
{
     jqCS603737("#comSImg603737_"+frameid+" img").attr("src", src).load(function(){
         if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth === 0)
         {
             //broken image
         }
     });
};
this.setNavStyle = function(id, background, color, border, type)
{
 if (background === "")
 {
     jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("background", "none");
 }
 else if (background == "transparent")
 {
     jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("background", "transparent");
 }
 else
 {
     jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("background", "#"+background);
 }
 jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("color", "#"+color);
 jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("border", border+"px solid #"+color);
 var margin = (-1)*border;
 jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("margin-top", margin+"px");
 jqCS603737("#comSNavigation603737_"+id).css("margin-left", margin+"px");
 if (type === 0)
 {
   jqCS603737("#comImgBullet603737_"+id).show();
   jqCS603737("#comImgBulletcurr603737_"+id).hide();
 }
 else
 {
   jqCS603737("#comImgBulletcurr603737_"+id).show();
   jqCS603737("#comImgBullet603737_"+id).hide();
 }
};
this.targetClearTimeouts = function()
{
 if (g_TransitionTimeoutRef != null)     { window.clearTimeout(g_TransitionTimeoutRef); g_TransitionTimeoutRef = null;}
};
this.getNextFrame = function()
{
 var ret = g_currFrame;
 ret++;
 if (ret == 9) {ret = 0;}
 return ret;
};
this.getPrevFrame = function()
{
 var ret = g_currFrame;
 ret--;
 if (ret < 0) {ret = (9-1);}
 return ret;
};
this.stopAll = function()
{
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_0").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_0").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_1").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_1").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_2").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_2").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_3").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_3").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_4").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_4").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_5").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_5").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_6").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_6").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_7").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_7").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_8").stop(true, true);
jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_8").stop(true, true);


};
this.switchFrame = function()
{
     g_Navigation = 1;
     var currFrame=g_currFrame;
     g_currFrame = self.getNextFrame();
     self.switchFromToFrame(currFrame, g_currFrame);
};

this.switchFramePrev = function()
{
     g_Navigation = 0;
     var currFrame=g_currFrame;
     g_currFrame = self.getPrevFrame();
     self.switchFromToFrame(currFrame, g_currFrame);
};

this.switchToFrame = function(toFrame)
{
     if ((g_InTransition == 1) || (g_currFrame == toFrame))
     {
         if (g_currFrame == toFrame) { return false; }
         self.stopAll();
     }
     var currFrame=g_currFrame;
     g_currFrame=toFrame;
     if (currFrame < g_currFrame)
         g_Navigation = 0;
     else
         g_Navigation = 1;
     self.switchFromToFrame(currFrame, g_currFrame);
};

this.switchFromToFrame =  function(currFrame, toFrame)
{
     if (g_InTransition == 1)
     {
         self.stopAll();
     }
g_InTransition = 1;
self.startTransitionTimer();
     jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_"+currFrame+"").css("z-index", 1);
     jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_"+toFrame+"").css("z-index", 2);
     jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_"+toFrame+"").hide().fadeIn(1350, function() { 
if (g_microID !=objcomSlider603737.getCurrMicroID()){return false;}jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_"+currFrame).hide(); g_InTransition = 0;
 } ); 
  self.setNavStyle(currFrame, '','CCCCCC',0, 0);  self.setNavStyle(toFrame, '','FFFFFF',0, 1);     jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_"+toFrame).show(1, function(){  });




};
this.startTransitionTimer = function()
{
  self.targetClearTimeouts(); g_TransitionTimeoutRef = window.setTimeout(function() {objcomSlider603737.onTransitionTimeout(g_microID);}, g_CycleTimeout*1000);
};
this.onTransitionTimeout = function(microID)
{
   if (g_microID != microID) { return false; }
     self.switchFrame();
};
this.initFrame = function()
{
g_currFrame = 0;
self.startTransitionTimer();
     jqCS603737("#comSFrameSek603737_"+g_currFrame+"").hide().fadeIn(1350);
  jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_"+g_currFrame).show(1, function(){if (g_microID !=objcomSlider603737.getCurrMicroID()){return false;}self.setNavStyle(g_currFrame, '','FFFFFF',0, 1);     });
  return true;
};

                    this.scriptLoaded = function()
                    {
                   jqCS603737 = jQuery603737.noConflict(false);jqCS603737("#comslider_in_point_603737").html('<div id="comSWrapper603737_" name="comSWrapper603737_" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; border:0px; width:740px; height:558px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><div id="comSWrapper603737_" name="comSWrapper603737_" style="overflow:hidden;border:0px; width:740px; height:558px; "><div id="comSFrameWrapper603737_" name="comSFrameWrapper603737_" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><div id="comSFrame603737_0" name="comSFrame603737_0" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_0" name="comSFrameSek603737_0" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_0" name="comSImg603737_0" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div><div id="comSHtml603737__bk0" name="comSHtml603737__bk0" style="background: #000000; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:249px; left:0px; width:740px; height:0px;"></div><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSHtml603737__bk0").fadeTo(0,0.5);</script><div id="comSHtml603737_0" name="comSHtml603737_0" style="padding:10px; background: transparent; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:249px; left:0px; width:740px; height:0px;"></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_1" name="comSFrame603737_1" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_1" name="comSFrameSek603737_1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_1" name="comSImg603737_1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_2" name="comSFrame603737_2" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_2" name="comSFrameSek603737_2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_2" name="comSImg603737_2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_3" name="comSFrame603737_3" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_3" name="comSFrameSek603737_3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_3" name="comSImg603737_3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_4" name="comSFrame603737_4" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_4" name="comSFrameSek603737_4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_4" name="comSImg603737_4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_5" name="comSFrame603737_5" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_5" name="comSFrameSek603737_5" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_5" name="comSImg603737_5" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_6" name="comSFrame603737_6" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_6" name="comSFrameSek603737_6" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_6" name="comSImg603737_6" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_7" name="comSFrame603737_7" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_7" name="comSFrameSek603737_7" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_7" name="comSImg603737_7" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div><div id="comSFrame603737_8" name="comSFrame603737_8" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSFrameSek603737_8" name="comSFrameSek603737_8" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><div id="comSImg603737_8" name="comSImg603737_8" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0px; left:0px; width:740px; height:498px;"><img style="border:0px; width:742px; height:498px;"></img></div></div></div></div><a name="0" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_0" name="comSNavigation603737_0" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:254px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_0" name="comImgBullet603737_0" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060925261521.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_0" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_0" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060925261521.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="1" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_1" name="comSNavigation603737_1" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:333px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_1" name="comImgBullet603737_1" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060930388851.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_1" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_1" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060930388851.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="2" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_2" name="comSNavigation603737_2" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_2" name="comImgBullet603737_2" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060936349581.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_2" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_2" src="comslider603737/imgnav/1504060936349581.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="3" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_3" name="comSNavigation603737_3" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_3" name="comImgBullet603737_3" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B4.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_3" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_3" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B4.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="4" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_4" name="comSNavigation603737_4" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_4" name="comImgBullet603737_4" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B5.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_4" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_4" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B5.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="5" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_5" name="comSNavigation603737_5" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_5" name="comImgBullet603737_5" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B6.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_5" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_5" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B6.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="6" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_6" name="comSNavigation603737_6" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_6" name="comImgBullet603737_6" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B7.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_6" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_6" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B7.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="7" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_7" name="comSNavigation603737_7" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_7" name="comImgBullet603737_7" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B8.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_7" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_7" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B8.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a><a name="8" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:40px;" href=""><div id="comSNavigation603737_8" name="comSNavigation603737_8" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute; height:50px; width:74px; top:503px; left:412px; z-index: 5; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  color: #CCCCCC;background: #; "><div id="height_workaround" style="font-size:1px;line-height:0;height:50px;">&nbsp;<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBullet603737_8" name="comImgBullet603737_8" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B9.png?timstamp=1428306527" /><img style="display: none; position: absolute; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:0px;" id="comImgBulletcurr603737_8" name="comImgBulletcurr603737_8" src="comslider603737/imgnav/B9.png?timstamp=1428306527" /></div></div></a></div><div id="comSNavigationControl603737__back" name="comSNavigationControl603737__back" style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; margin-left:5px; border: 0px; position:absolute; height:32px; width:32px; top:233px; left:0px; z-index: 6; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom;  background-color: transparent; "><img class="def" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 0px;" src="comslider603737/imgnavctl/defback.png?1428306431" /><img class="hover" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display:none; border: 0px;" src="comslider603737/imgnavctl/defbackhover.png?1428306431" /></div><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back").bind(\'mouseenter\', function() {  jqCS603737(this).css(\'background-color\', \'transparent\'); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back img.hover").show(); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back img.def").hide(); });</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back").bind(\'mouseleave\', function() {  jqCS603737(this).css(\'background-color\', \'transparent\'); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back img.def").show();  jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back img.hover").hide(); });</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back").bind(\'click\', function() { objcomSlider603737.switchFramePrev(); });</script><div id="comSNavigationControl603737__forward" name="comSNavigationControl603737__forward" style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; margin-left:-5px; border: 0px; position:absolute; height:32px; width:32px; top:233px; left:708px; z-index: 6; text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom; background-color: transparent; "><img class="def" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 0px;" src="comslider603737/imgnavctl/defforward.png?1428306431" /><img class="hover" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display:none; border: 0px;" src="comslider603737/imgnavctl/defforwardhover.png?1428306431" /></div><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward").bind(\'mouseenter\', function() {  jqCS603737(this).css(\'background-color\', \'transparent\'); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward img.hover").show(); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward img.def").hide(); });</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward").bind(\'mouseleave\', function() {  jqCS603737(this).css(\'background-color\', \'transparent\'); jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward img.def").show();  jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward img.hover").hide(); });</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward").bind(\'click\', function() { objcomSlider603737.switchFrame(); });</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__back").fadeTo(0,0.8);</script><script type="text/javascript"> jqCS603737("#comSNavigationControl603737__forward").fadeTo(0,0.8);</script></div>');
                    jqCS603737("#comslider_in_point_603737 a").bind('click',  function() { if ((this.name.length > 0) && (isNaN(this.name) === false)) {  self.switchToFrame(parseInt(this.name)); return false;} });
                self.comSLoadImgInFrame("0", "comslider603737/img/1504060925261521.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_0").hide();
self.comSLoadImgInFrame("1", "comslider603737/img/1504060930388851.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_1").hide();
self.comSLoadImgInFrame("2", "comslider603737/img/1504060936349581.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_2").hide();
self.comSLoadImgInFrame("3", "comslider603737/img/B4.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_3").hide();
self.comSLoadImgInFrame("4", "comslider603737/img/B5.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_4").hide();
self.comSLoadImgInFrame("5", "comslider603737/img/B6.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_5").hide();
        self.comSLoadImgInFrame("6", "comslider603737/img/B7.png?1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_6").hide();
    self.comSLoadImgInFrame("7", "comslider603737/img/B8.png?    1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_7").hide();
    self.comSLoadImgInFrame("8", "comslider603737/img/B9.png?    1428306431");jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_8").hide();

    jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_8").hide();
    jqCS603737("#comSFrame603737_8").hide();

    self.initFrame();

    };
    var g_CSIncludes = new Array();
    var g_CSLoading = false;
    var g_CSCurrIdx = 0; 
     this.include = function(src, last) 
                {
                    if (src !== '')
                    {               
                            var tmpInclude = Array();
                            tmpInclude[0] = src;
                            tmpInclude[1] = last;                   
                            //
                            g_CSIncludes[g_CSIncludes.length] = tmpInclude;
                    }            
                    if ((g_CSLoading === false) && (g_CSCurrIdx <     g_CSIncludes.length))
                    {


                            var oScript = null;
                            if (g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx][0].split('.').pop() ==     'css')
                            {
                                oScript = document.createElement('link');
                                oScript.href = g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx][0];
                                oScript.type = 'text/css';
                                oScript.rel = 'stylesheet';

                                oScript.onloadDone = true; 
                                g_CSLoading = false;
                                g_CSCurrIdx++;                              
                                if (g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx-1][1] === true) 
                                        self.scriptLoaded(); 
                                else
                                        self.include('', false);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                oScript = document.createElement('script');
                                oScript.src = g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx][0];
                                oScript.type = 'text/javascript';

                                //oScript.onload = scriptLoaded;
                                oScript.onload = function() 
                                { 
                                        if ( ! oScript.onloadDone ) 
                                        {
                                                oScript.onloadDone = true; 
                                                g_CSLoading = false;
                                                g_CSCurrIdx++;                              
                                                if (g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx-1][1]     === true) 
                                                        self.scriptLoaded(); 
                                                else
                                                        self.include('', false);
                                        }
                                };
                                oScript.onreadystatechange = function() 
                                { 
                                        if ( ( "loaded" === oScript.readyState ||     "complete" === oScript.readyState ) && ! oScript.onloadDone ) 
                                        {
                                                oScript.onloadDone = true;
                                                g_CSLoading = false;    
                                                g_CSCurrIdx++;
                                                if (g_CSIncludes[g_CSCurrIdx-1][1]     === true) 
                                                        self.scriptLoaded(); 
                                                else
                                                        self.include('', false);
                                        }
                                };

                            }
                            //
                                document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(oScript);
                            //
                            g_CSLoading = true;
                    }

                };


    }
    objcomSlider603737 = new comSlider603737();
    objcomSlider603737.include('comslider603737/js/helpers.js', false);
    objcomSlider603737.include('comslider603737/js/jquery-1.10.1.js', false);
    objcomSlider603737.include('comslider603737/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.effects.js',               true);
```

Comment: Buddy.. It will be good if you post any fiddle for this!

Comment: i have no idea what that is

Comment: You can paste your `html,css and js` into fiddle, save it and give us the link so that we can try editing your code and achieve what you want. **[Visit here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html)** for more info. Link to **jsfiddle** is **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: seems like i have a problem with jsfiddle, because my js past has html and my html has script part. i think i just made a small mistake somewhere in a code, because everything works fine, it just doesn't get all the thumbnails, just three